# UNIX: Conditional check results in unexpected result

Tags: bash, ps

I am reading the PID from a file and trying to check, if that variable does exist and a corresponding process, too:

```
#!/bin/bash
# startScript.sh
pidFile=startScript.sh.pid

# Read PID from file
PID=$(cat $pidFile)
echo "PID read from file: $PID"

# Check, if process with PID exists
if ( [ -n "$PID" ] && [ ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null ] )
then
    echo "$PID is already running"
else
    # Start node script and retrieve its PID
    node index.js &
    PID=$!
    # Create a file with current PID to indicate that process is running.
    echo $PID > "$pidFile"
    echo "Script started with PID $PID"
fi
exit 1
```

I'd like to check both conditions in one go to avoid duplicating the start of the node script. After reading the comments, I corrected the first condition but now I do get the error

`./startScript.sh: line 11: [: -p: binary operator expected`

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any hint?

Comment: `[ -z "$PID" ] && [ ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null ]` does not make sense: If `PID` is empty, you do a `ps -p`, but you then don't have a pid. Hence, the command executed is just `ps -p ""`, which always sets the exit code to zero. Perhaps you meant `[ -n "$PID" ]`?

Comment: Thanks, first condition adapted but now getting an error.

Comment: `if ( [ -n "$PID" ] && [ ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null ] )` should simply be `if [ -n "$PID" ] && ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null; then ...` No need for `(...)` and no need for `[...]` around `ps -p ...`

Comment: @AntonSack : As David C. Rankin explained, the error comes because you are effectively doing a `test ps -p "$PID"`, because `[` is just a shortcut for `test`. If you look at `man test`, you see that this statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit; your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to post an answer, by all means do.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Bash manual page on `if`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> ```
> if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
> ```
>
> The `if list` is executed.  If its exit status is **zero**, the `then` list is executed.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

That means you think the process is running if the string `"$PID"` is *empty*, which it can only be if the file doesn't exist or is empty itself.

Using `-n` as condition to check `"$PID"` would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks, first condition adapted but now getting error `./startScript.sh: line 11: [: -p: binary operator expected`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Thanks to the comments, I changed my condition to

```
if [ -n "$PID" ] && ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null;
```

which works fine.

Thanks a lot!